# How do I make constrictor methods non-distructive?

Tags: java, methods

I'm trying to make a constrictor that will act like a matrix. But I'm having trouble understanding why sometimes the methods in my constrictor are destructive (They alter the values passed into them).

An example is below:

This is part of my Matrix constrictor with a method used for element by element subtraction:

```
static class Matrix {
        double[][] data;

        public Matrix subtract(Matrix matrix) {
            Matrix output = new Matrix();

            output.data = this.data;

            if(this.data.length == matrix.data.length && this.data[0].length == matrix.data[0].length){
                for(int i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++)
                    for(int j = 0; j < this.data[0].length; j++)
                        output.data[i][j] = this.data[i][j] - matrix.data[i][j];
            }

            return output;
        }
```

And here is some simple code to make 2 Matrix's (A and B) subtract them and put the resault in another Matrix (called C).

```
        Matrix A = new Matrix();
        Matrix B = new Matrix();

        A.data = new double[][]{ {1,2,3},
                                 {4,5,6}};

        B.data = new double[][]{ {7,8,9},
                                 {10,11,12}};

        System.out.println("Before: ");
        System.out.println("A: " + Arrays.deepToString(A.data));
        System.out.println("B: " + Arrays.deepToString(B.data));

        Matrix C = A.subtract(B);

        System.out.println("After: ");
        System.out.println("A: " + Arrays.deepToString(A.data));
        System.out.println("B: " + Arrays.deepToString(B.data));
        System.out.println("C: " + Arrays.deepToString(C.data));
```

The command line output is as follows:

```
Before: 
A: [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]]
B: [[7.0, 8.0, 9.0], [10.0, 11.0, 12.0]]
After: 
A: [[-6.0, -6.0, -6.0], [-6.0, -6.0, -6.0]]
B: [[7.0, 8.0, 9.0], [10.0, 11.0, 12.0]]
C: [[-6.0, -6.0, -6.0], [-6.0, -6.0, -6.0]]
```

As you can see, the values in Matrix A changed after the subtraction was performed, despite the contents of A never being over written.

Can someone help me understand why this happens and how I can avoid it?
Thank you!

Comment: "*`output.data = this.data;`*" - This line does not do what you think it does. It does not copy the array, only the reference to the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement

```
        output.data = this.data;
```

makes the 'output' of the subtract method be the same array-of-arrays as the 'input'.

The only thing you're copying is a single reference to the data.

This is tied in to the distinction between objects and references in the language.  Variables only hold references, never objects.

Thus

```
        output.data[i][j]
```

and

```
        this.data[i][j]
```

are the same location in memory.

Comment: So if I did something like ```output.data = new double[this.data.length][this.data[0].length];``` I could get around this issue?

Comment: @Royginald Yes.